# How to get a child link on python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
<div class="class_one"><a href="link"></a></div>
```

I do this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(path.text, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all("div", { "class" : "class_one"}):
```

I use a regular expression to get the href link. Is there another solution with Beautiful Soup?

Answer (score 1):

```
for link in soup.find_all("div", { "class" : "class_one"}):
    a = link.next_element
    print(a)
```

out:

```
<a href="link"></a>
```

The .next_element attribute of a string or tag points to whatever was parsed immediately afterwards.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One (probably inefficient) solution would be to grab all `a` items in your `div` and access their `href`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(this, 'html.parser')
for linkdiv in soup.find_all("div", { "class" : "class_one"}):
    targets = [link.get('href') for link in linkdiv.find_all('a')]
    print(targets[0])
```